# Rstudio Webscraping - Rvest returns character(0)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm working on an undergraduate project that I am required to webscrape the following data from multiple airbnb listings.

Here is an example:
https://www.airbnb.com.sg/rooms/49091?_set_bev_on_new_domain=1582777903_ZWE4MTBjMGNmYmFh&source_impression_id=p3_1582778001_lB%2BjT8%2BWgIsL%2FrBV

The following data I am required to webscrape is 1 guest, 1 bedroom, 1 bed, 1 bathroom.
However, when I use the CSS selector tool, my following path is "._b2fuovg".

This returns character(0) when I run the following code.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url1 <- read_html("https://www.airbnb.com.sg/rooms/49091?_set_bev_on_new_domain=1582777903_ZWE4MTBjMGNmYmFh&source_impression_id=p3_1582778001_lB%2BjT8%2BWgIsL%2FrBV")
url1 %>%
  html_nodes("._b2fuovg") %>%
  html_text()
```

and the following output is

```
> url1 %>%
+   html_nodes("._b2fuovg") %>%
+   html_text()
character(0)
```

Any advice or guidance in the right direction is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Selector Gadget to determine what node to scrape: https://selectorgadget.com/

It works by clicking on the information you want. Other information that will also be included will be shown in yellow. If you don't want those, click on them to turn them red. You will notice at the bottom of your screen a little bar with some text. This is what you want to include in `html_nodes()`. In this case, I got "._1b3ij9t+ div". Sure enough, this seems to work:

```
url1 %>%
  html_nodes("._1b3ij9t+ div") %>%
  html_text()
[1] "1 guest · 1 bedroom · 1 bed · 1 bathroom"
```

Comment: hi, why selector gadget gives me this `.liveticker-a__date , .liveticker-a__head` when I scrape title and date from this [site](https://today.rtl.lu/news/luxembourg/a/1481968.html) while R gives me **character(0)** in the console?